# extracting elements out of a json object inside an postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have been trying to learn how to do a select query on a table that has a jsonb variable.

basically the table is called cardtech and the variable is data

```
 {
"cardTransaction": [
    {
        "ppan": "482003PAYXMO3770",
        "time": "2020-03-21T00:00:00",
        "type": "205",
        "amount": {
            "ccy": "IDR",
            "value": 325105
        },
```

is one of the records.

in all the other tables i was able to extract data using

```
 data->customer->>ppan as ppan
```

But with this I cant seem to get past the first section and no matter what I try I can only get the full object.

I am looking for some help on how to extract the first element of cardTransaction which is ppan.

to create a new view table.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Comment: data->customer->>ppan as ppan <-- was another table with the object customer

Answer (score 1):

The element for the key `cardTransaction` is an array, so you need to access the object by index

```
data -> 'cardTransaction' -> 0 ->> 'ppan'
```

The `'cardTransaction' -> 0` [selects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) the first element of the array identified by the key `'cardTransaction'`

Unlike native Postgres arrays, JSON arrays start with index 0

Comment: Thank you!!! that makes perfect sense.. been looking at every single example on the web and missed the point..